# Apache LocationMatch: how to match again after internal redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a apache LocationMatch with two sets of RewriteCond and RewriteRule. If the second set hits I want to start the LoactionMatch over again.

In my apache2 ( Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.9.0 Python/3.8 configured) config I have something like this:

```
<LocationMatch ^/incoming-request$>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond /tmp/test-file -f
    RewriteRule (.*) /some/service [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond /file-associated-with-the-request -f
    RewriteRule (.*) /myapp [L]

</LocationMatch>
```

Where `myapp` is a wsgi script which generates the `/tmp/test-file` and returns `301 redirect` and `Location: /incoming-request`

`/file-associated-with-the-request` always exists.

So far so good.

If the `/tmp/test-file` does not exists then trigger the `/myapp` which then generates the `/tmp/test-file`. Then I want the `LocationMatch` to start over again so that the `/some/service`
is triggered as `/tmp/test-file` exists after the first loop. This does not happen.

If I `curl http://localhost/incoming-request` I get the `/tmp/test-file` generated, and I get the return from `/myapp`. So if I want to get the return from `/some/service` I have to run the curl again.

Is there a way to kind of loop over again in the `LocationMatch` so I dont have to do my request twice?

Comment: "after internal redirect" - But the "301 redirect" is an external redirect, not internal. Apache would need to somehow generate another HTTP request internally for it to do what you require - this does not happen. Presumably you are seeing the redirect response when you run CURL? You need to use the `-L` flag to get CURL to follow the redirect and issue a second request (like a browser would do by default). (However, you should avoid using mod_rewrite directives inside a `<LocationMatch>` block. Why are you checking the existence of a file that "always exists"?)

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite. I just figured out the curl `-L` flag, and that way it now works. I used `<LocationMatch>` because I will need many different locations triggering different rewrites. I don't know how I could achieve this with out this.